Aggregation with timeout and group size takes a lot of time
I have this integration flow
IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.queue(MailPushGateway.SEND_MAIL_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.headerExpression(TracingConstants.USER_ID, "payload.getUser()"))
                .transform(Message.class, mailPushTransformer::toPushNotification)
                .aggregate(aggregatorSpec -> aggregatorSpec
                        .expireGroupsUponTimeout(true)
                        .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                        .expireTimeout(1000)
                        .requiresReply(false)
                        .messageStore(new SimpleMessageStore(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                        .async(true)
                        .correlationStrategy(message -> true)
                        .releaseStrategy(new TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy(600, 1000))
                        .notPropagatedHeaders(TracingConstants.USER_ID)
                        .headersFunction(messageGroup -> Map.of(TracingConstants.MESSAGES_IDS,MailPushFlow.collectMessageIds(messageGroup)))
                        .outputProcessor(MailPushFlow::extractPayload)
                        .advice(requestHandlerRetryAdvice)
                        .releaseLockBeforeSend(true)
                )
                .handle(mailPushService, "sendMailPushNotificationChunk",
                        e -> e.id(MAIL_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_GATEWAY)
                                .advice(this.requestHandlerRetryAdvice)
                                .async(true)
                                .requiresReply(false))
                .get();

I thought that with TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy messages are sent by sequence, but if I check the execution time (based on the older message timestamp) it seems that the aggregation takes about 40 sec and then it slowly decreases to 1-2 sec.
What's wrong with this configuration? I need to send message groups based on the arrival sequence

@gary-russell I'm praying for your help

Gary Russell went to retirement, so he is not with the team any more.
You don't have a proper grouping in your config. The .correlationStrategy(message -> true) means that all incoming messages are going to be added to the same group. it is probably better to explain what is the logic and what an expectation from the aggregation, rather than trying to make a sense from your current code snippet.

Hi Artem, thank you for reply! I need to group by earliest timestamps. For example, I have messages with timestamps T1, T2, T3, T4 and I need to aggregate T1 and T2, then T3 and T4

Sounds like windowing by time: https://www.oreilly.com/radar/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-101/. So, you need to figure out a period of time to decide which message fits into it. The period and multiplier could be as a group id (correlation key).
So, let's imaging the grouping aspect is 10 seconds period. So, the first group is in the interval 0-10. The next 11-20 and so on. You definitely can have group id as those interval definitions: 0-10, 11-20, 21-30 etc.
The custom CorrelationStrategy would calculate that group id according to the message timestamp. Unfortunately, this has nothing to do with the framework. You just need to work out a business model and implement respective strategy.

I found TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy that completes groups reaching a certain size or a timeout from the earliest message in a queuechannel with "correlationStrategy(message -> true)"  and it seems it's working fine.
The only "bug" i've found is when I send the first message to the aggregator, it waits for the second message to enable the release strategy. There is a way to solve this or should I override "canRelease()" method with a custom logic?

I forgot groupTimeout, now it's working fine!
